# Convert Greasemonkey script into an injectable JS (no addons)

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, javascript-injection

Thank you in advance for your assistance. Basically I'm using Rambox Pro (basic browser with injecting JS & CSS support only) into webpages as my workstation & I'm using Notion & want this particular Greasemonkey script in Rambox Pro. I'm hoping to do so by injecting it in (by the JS option).

Orignal [link](https://www.notion.so/Notion-Inline-Math-9c5047a4e7c84643848b3630db8d5a5e) to post & the [link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/evertheylen/notion-inline-math/master/script.js) to the specific JS script.

I have gone as far as altering out the GM_addstyle into a `document.body.appendChild` by help here (but get a console timeout error), hence not using GM. I ignored the timeout error & tried to use the script but I get an error Katex is unknown so i  tried to import Katex with `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.10.0/dist/katex.js"></script>` but i keep getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` error

I've since given up on trying to convert it myself - could anyone help me convert this script fully into purely injectable JS. The code is: (copied from link)

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name Inline Math for Notion.so
// @homepageURL https://www.notion.so/evertheylen/Notion-Inline-Math-9c5047a4e7c84643848b3630db8d5a5e
// @version 0.2.1
// @match https://www.notion.so/*
// @grant GM_addStyle
// @require https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.10.0/dist/katex.js
// ==/UserScript==

// Instructions for use:
//   - Make sure you have at least one normal math block on your page
//   - Use inline code starting with "math:". For example: `math: f(x) = x^2`
//   - Press F2 to rerender all inline math. You can of course change the shortcut in the code below.
//   - The inline math will revert to inline code when the block becomes active.

GM_addStyle(`
.notion-frame span .katex {
    padding-right: 0 !important;
}
`)

function rerender_all() {
    var code = document.querySelectorAll("span[style*=\"monospace\"]")
    code.forEach(function(el) {
        var s = el.textContent
        if (s.startsWith("math:")) {
            el.style.color = null
            el.style.background = null
            s = s.slice(5).trim()
            console.log("rendering ", s)
            katex.render(s, el, {throwOnError: false, font: 'mathit'})
        }
    })
}

window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.key == "F7" && !e.ctrlKey && !e.shiftKey && !e.altKey) {
        console.log("rerender!");
        rerender_all()
    }
}, true)

// I don't know a good way to trigger rerender automatically yet
//document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', rerender_all, false);
```

Side-note, if relevant - I am injecting CSS into it too (if matters) and
RamboxPro does not support any extensions (just injection of JS & CSS) (It has the normal web developer mode). I am of any assistance if needed should this be possible/feasible.

Also - there is no need to check if the page is right (if it matters) as the JS & CSS injections are app independent (aka I'll be only injection this on the notion app that loads the notion pages)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GreaseMonkey script is just JavaScript.

One consideration is the GM APIs which in this case is `// @grant GM_addStyle`

1- Change

```
GM_addStyle(`
.notion-frame span .katex {
    padding-right: 0 !important;
}
`)
```

change to:

```
const style = document.createElement('style');
style.textContent = `.notion-frame span .katex { padding-right: 0 !important; }`;
(document.head || document.body).appendChild(style);
```

2- get the `@require`

```
const script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.10.0/dist/katex.js';
(document.head || document.body).appendChild(script);
```

3- You need a method to inject the script into the target location i.e. `https://www.notion.so/*`

Here is an example of the reworked user-script. You still need a method to inject it.

```
// inject CSS
const style = document.createElement('style');
style.textContent = `.notion-frame span .katex { padding-right: 0 !important; }`;
(document.head || document.body).appendChild(style);

const script1 = document.createElement('script');
script1.textContent = `
// inject the script to run after remtoe scritp is loaded
function runCode() {
    function rerender_all() {
        var code = document.querySelectorAll('span[style*="monospace"]')
        code.forEach(function(el) {
            var s = el.textContent
            if (s.startsWith("math:")) {
                el.style.color = null
                el.style.background = null
                s = s.slice(5).trim()
                console.log("rendering ", s)
                katex.render(s, el, {throwOnError: false, font: 'mathit'})
            }
        })
    }

    window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
        if (e.key == "F7" && !e.ctrlKey && !e.shiftKey && !e.altKey) {
            console.log("rerender!");
            rerender_all()
        }
    }, true)
  }
`;
document.body.appendChild(script1);


// wait for the external script to laod
const script2 = document.createElement('script');
script2.onload = runCode;
(document.head || document.body).appendChild(script2);
script2.src = 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.10.0/dist/katex.js';
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm unsure what do you mean by I still need a method to inject it though. The applications provides 2 boxes in which I can paste the code I wish to inject for javascript & CSS. Thanks again, after trying to inject in the JS side, I get an error in the console for the last line of it:

`VM295:39 Refused to load the script 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.10.0/dist/katex.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' ...`

Does this mean the 'injection' works but fails due to security policy?

Comment: @user13050686 Script can be injected by various methods and I was not familiar with how you wanted to do so (in this case your application has a method). The application is injecting the script into page content and therefore it will be subject to page CSP (Content Security Policy). You can copy the `katex.js` content and paste it in `script1.textContent`

Comment: Thank You it worked! After a while of tinkering around with it. I replaced the GMaddstyle as you directed & then pasted the `katex.js` code in the `script1.textContent`. I did, however, leave the functions & the added `katex.js` code as it was not placing them in a script element & it worked! Thanks a lot for the assistance & pushing me in the right direction :)!